# how to find the Strings which are hard-coded in xHtmls

Tags: javascript, java, xhtml, string-externalization

how to find the Strings which are hard-coded in xHtmls and java code base. The purpose is to externalize them as part of localization. I mean they are not in a particular pattern to use regex to find them.  is there a third party tool which can automate? or do I have to do it manually? 
example for hard-coded string: 
if the text is in the form of:

```
<xyz:param
     name = "cat"
     value = "meow">
```

here the string "meow" is hard coded. But if its defined in prop.file and used in the form of

```
 <xyz:param
     name = "cat"
     value = "#{msgXYZ['msg.services.cat.meow']}">
```

then its externalized. All good.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more context here. What kind of strings are we looking at? Just text in HTML, such as `<title>Dit is een titel</title>` that will need to be translated? Is there some tool you're using for this?

Comment: Also, what is the [javascript] tag for?